# AngularJS Sharepoint Online App - JSON REST - cannot find list or list items or field values

Tags: json, angularjs, rest, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

I want to create an app that is using AngularJS to get information from my list and get the values from every list item. It works fine when I place all my code into a Script Editor on the page where I link my angular.js file. I can for example get the Title from each item by specify {{item.Title}} in the Script Editor, which will show the title (Item1).

But now I want to deploy an app part to do the same thing, so I just can place the app part on my page instead of writing a lot of code in a Script Editor. So I created a SharePoint app in Visual Studio and copy the contents from .css, .js and .aspx. If we say that my url to this SharePoint site is: https://sharepointonline365.sharepoint.com/sites/devsite/. When I deploy the app, it gets deployed to https://sharepointonline365-f7a048d3d91264.sharepoint.com/sites/devsite/MyApp instead. Therefore, it shows {{item.Title}} instead of Item1 as it did when I used a Script Editor. It just can't find my items. I also get the following error on my angular code: Validation (HTML5): Attribute 'ng-controller' is not a valid of element 'div'. My code looks like this:

```
<div ng-app="spApp">
<div ng-controller="scopeCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in Items" class="archive1">
        {{item.Title}
    </div>
</div>
```

```
var spApp = angular.module('spApp', []);
spApp.controller('scopeCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
$http(
{
    method: "GET",
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('TestList')/items?$select=Title",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }
}
).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.Items= data.d.results;

}).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

});
});
```

It doesn't find my angular. What am I doing wrong? Please help!

KR

Comment: Where is your angular.js file?  How are you referencing it.

Comment: I am referencing the angular.min.js by https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.min.js and then referencing my js which is the second code snippet under the html

Comment: Can you post the full html from your app

Answer (score 0):

from what you posted there is little i can advice you

1. since you cant upload server code anyway use Sharepoint Designer to upload you files to sharepoint
2. sometimes CDNs takes a bitzy little longer to load, and with sharepoint i saw impacts sometimes, to try using angular with an anugluar.js file instead of cdn.
3. sharepoint scripts do not stop nor finish when the document is ready, nor after it. angular waits for the document ready event to finish and starts. try to init angular with the sharepoint callback _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames like this

   ```
   function runAfterEverythingElse() {
   //do stuff like spApp = angular.module('spApp', []);
   };
   _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("runAfterEverythingElse");
   ```

for more help, as commented, please put full code